# devise.en.yml not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

For those of you who are familiar with Devise, and it's functionality you should have some working knowledge of the Devise.en.yml file in the config/locales directory. This file essentially creates error messages when logging in, i.e: if you type in a password thats wrong you should see an error message like "invalid: 'Invalid email or password.".

In my case it isn't functioning, if I type in the wrong user name/password nothing happens it just doesn't log you in, but there is no flash message.

My devise.en.yml file contents are all green, i'm not sure if this how it is supposed to look but I have a hunch that something isn't right with the code maybe? But that may or may not be the actual reason.

Not sure which controllers or contents to include so as soon as you ask, i'll update the OP with them.

#### here is the devise.en.yml file for my app:

```
  en:
  errors:
  messages:
  not_found: "not found"
  already_confirmed: "was already confirmed"
  not_locked: "was not locked"

  devise:
    failure:
      unauthenticated: 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.'
      unconfirmed: 'You have to confirm your account before continuing.'
      locked: 'Your account is locked.'
      invalid: 'Invalid email or password.'
      invalid_token: 'Invalid authentication token.'
      timeout: 'Your session expired, please sign in again to continue.'
      inactive: 'Your account was not activated yet.'
    sessions:
      signed_in: 'Signed in successfully.'
      signed_out: 'Signed out successfully.'
    passwords:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to reset your password in a few minutes.'
      updated: 'Your password was changed successfully. You are now signed in.'
    confirmations:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes.'
      confirmed: 'Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in.'
    registrations:
      signed_up: 'You have signed up successfully.'
      updated: 'You updated your account successfully.'
      destroyed: 'Bye! Your account was successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon.'
    unlocks:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to unlock your account in a few minutes.'
      unlocked: 'Your account was successfully unlocked. You are now signed in.'
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions: 'Confirmation instructions'
      reset_password_instructions: 'Reset password instructions'
      unlock_instructions: 'Unlock Instructions'
```

Comment: My first question would be: are flash messages broken just for Devise, or for your whole application?

Comment: Thats a great question, i've tried adding flash messages in other areas of the app, and they don't seem to be working anywhere.

Comment: Okay. My guess is that your flash message code disappeared from `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` at some point. Maybe check there and add the flash code if it's not there.

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to the .yml file.  How are you trying to display the flash messages?  Also, is the `devise_error_messages` fragment in place in your view?  This would show the error as a static message.

Comment: Both of the comments make sense. @JasonSwett which flash code would I add to application.html.erb? that is presumably it.

Comment: Posted code in answer. I hope that does it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have to add this code to `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
  <% if notice %>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <% end %>

  <% if alert %>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Note: if you're using Twitter Bootstrap, you may need to use `<%= bootstrap_flash %>` instead of what's above.

Comment: I think that is working, but it looks like the flash message is hidden  under my nav? if that makes sense. The reason I say that is, when I click sign-in now the content moves down as if something is there but it's as if the flash msg is hidden behind the nav header.

Comment: Update: to test my hypotheses i've removed my nav header and low and behold the flash message was there! Anyway to control where it is output?

Comment: I'd recommend temporarily changing the notice/alert code above to something hard-coded, and without the `if`s, like `<p class="notice">blah blah blah</p>`. Then style them how you'd like, then set it back to what it originally was.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the real problem, but as an idea.

Yaml uses identation for scoping. Not sure if it was broken when you were copy-pasting here, but if not, you problem may be that your devise.en.yml file should look like:

```
en:
  errors: 
    messages:
      not_found: "not found"
      ...
  devise:
    failure:
       ...
```

and not how it looks now in your question. Also, check that you use spaces, not tabs for identation.